# Adding a completion handler to Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm working on a small chunk of Swift code to work with pulling data via web-based APIs. Right now I am close, but think I'm missing the completion handler aspect when I print the data within the getUserInfo() expected data is there, but outside that function, the initialized default data appears. The function is called like this:

```
print("Provided Username is: \(workingData.user)")
getUserInfo()
print("Returned String Data is: \(workingData.responseDataString)")
```

and the actual function:

```
func getUserInfo() {
    Alamofire.request(workingjss.jssURL + devAPIMatchPath + workingData.user, method: .get)
        .authenticate(user: workingjss.jssUsername, password: workingjss.jssPassword).responseString { response in
            if (response.result.isSuccess) {
                print("In Function Data: \(response.result.value!)"
                workingData.responseDataString = response.result.value!
            }
    }
}
```

The output in running the code is:

```
Provided Username is: MYUSER
Returned String Data is: Nothing Here Yet 
In Function Data: {"Cleaned JSON Data here"}
```

Would a completion handler help the issue out? I'm pretty new to working with Alamofire so sorry if this is an easy one. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Try using a completion handler:

```
func getUserInfo(completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
    Alamofire.request(workingjss.jssURL + devAPIMatchPath + workingData.user, method: .get)
        .authenticate(user: workingjss.jssUsername, password: workingjss.jssPassword).responseString { response in
            if (response.result.isSuccess) {
                print("In Function Data: \(response.result.value!)"
                completion(response.result.value!)
            }
    }
}
```

And call it like:

```
getUserInfo() { response in
    // Do your stuff here
    workingData.responseDataString = response
    print("Returned String Data is: \(workingData.responseDataString)")
}
```